# Select unique id with a given code, but not if it has a another row with a different code with a later timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table that basically consists of a user id, a code(A or B) and a timestamp.

I need to get a list of unique ids that have a code of A, but only if that same user id does not also have a row with code B with a later timestamp.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Sample data and desired results are a big boost to conveying a question.

Answer (score 1):

This English query translates into SQL almost verbatim:

> get a list of unique ids that have a code of A

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM user u WHERE code='A' <...>
```

> but only if that same user id does not also have a row with code B with a later timestamp

```
<...> AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM user ou
    WHERE ou.user_id=u.user_id AND ou.code='B' AND ou.time_stamp > u.time_stamp
)
```

The trick to the translation us the use of *aliases*: `u` stands for "User", while `ou` stands for "Other user". Hence `ou.user_id=u.user_id AND ou.code='B' AND ou.time_stamp > u.time_stamp` means "another user with the same `id`, code of `'B'`, and a later timestamp".

Answer (score 1):

This will get the result with only a single table scan:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( user_id, code, time ) AS
SELECT 1, 'A', TIMESTAMP '2016-02-01 00:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'A', TIMESTAMP '2016-02-02 00:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'A', TIMESTAMP '2016-02-01 00:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'B', TIMESTAMP '2016-02-02 00:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'B', TIMESTAMP '2016-02-01 00:00:00' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'A', TIMESTAMP '2016-02-02 00:00:00' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM  (
  SELECT user_id,
         code,
         LEAD( CASE code WHEN 'B' THEN 1 END )
           IGNORE NULLS
           OVER ( PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY time ASC )
           AS has_b
  FROM   TABLE_NAME
)
WHERE  code = 'A'
AND    has_b IS NULL;
```

**Output**:

```
   USER_ID
----------
         1 
         3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT userId FROM tblName WHERE code = 'A' AND WHERE userId =
(SELECT userId FROM tblName WHERE code != 'B')
```